# MongoDB Text Index on all Fields using Java

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

I want to create a text index on all of my fields in MongoDB. I know that it can be done like this:

`db.collection.ensureIndex({ "$**": "text" },{ name: "TextIndex" })`

But I want create this index in my Java program. I tried with this:

`collection.createIndex(new BasicDBObject("$**","text"),newBasicDBObject("name","TextIndex"));`

but it gave me this error:
`com.mongodb.MongoException: Can't canonicalize query: BadValue unknown operator: $**`

I don't know what to do. I can see that others have asked the similar question but no one answered. Can any of you guys help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Text search is a rather new feature. Are you maybe using an outdated version of the java driver? Or maybe even of MongoDB itself? Text search must be enabled through a config parameter in 2.4 and doesn't exist in prior versions.

Comment: Yes I know. Both my MongoDB and Java driver are their latest release. I can create an index on one field and it's working but I want to create index on all fields.

Comment: Oh, it seems that my Java Driver was not actually the latest release. I got the newest release and now it works like a charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oops, it seems that my Java Driver was not actually the latest release. I got the newest release and now it works like a charm.

***Always download your libs from the maven repos.***