# How to index on all fields in spring data mongodb?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, indexing, spring-data-mongodb

Say I have some collection called candidates. I want to create a `text` index on all fields inside this collection. In mongo, I know that I can do it this way

```
db.candidates.createIndex({"$**":"text"},{name:"TextIndex"})
```

Here is my java pojo or entity.

```
@Document(collection = "candidates")
public class Candidate {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

   // Other stuff: removed for brevity
}
```

Now how do I do `db.candidates.createIndex({"$**":"text"},{name:"TextIndex"})` in java? That is how do I index an entire pojo or how do I do index all fields in my collection?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25323695/mongodb-text-index-on-all-fields-using-java) tried to do the same thing, but it does not have full details.

Also I looked at [`@Indexed`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/index/Indexed.html) annotation, however how can I use to index an entire collection since it can only be applied to a field?

Comment: Nope that is not the JPA API.

Comment: Ok, so is there a way to do it without JPA then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With @TextIndexed you can at least index all the field you want to include in your index. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/index/TextIndexed.html

Alternatively you can use the mongotemplate for this. [How to set @TextIndex name in an entity with Spring-Data-MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39377546/how-to-set-textindex-name-in-an-entity-with-spring-data-mongodb)

Comment: So if I were to use textindexed annotation, does that mean that I have to put it on all fields? I have like 40 fields or so and I dont want to repeat this. Is there a way to put an annotation on class level itself? thanks